# Nuxt build only from git committed sources

Tags: git, nuxt.js

As the title says, is there a way to build for deployment in Nuxt while ignoring any uncommitted changes?

Comment: Either checkout in a new empty directory. Or stash uncommitted changes, build and unstash them back.

Comment: @phd good idea with stash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per phd's suggestion this is the build script in `package.json`:

```json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "git stash -u; nuxt build; git stash pop"
    ...
  }
...
}
```